# Non parametric Hypothesis test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric

Suppose that I want to implement a non parametric hypothesis for a skewness estimator and check if it is equal to 0. Is my following thought correct ??

Suppose that we somehow estimate the skewness $s_{1}$ for a specific sample. We also know that that skewness of a normal distribution is 0. Thus, what I'm thinking is to generate like 10.000 samples from a gaussian distribution calculate the skewness $s_{2j}$ where $j=1,..,10.000$ and calculate $s_{1}-s_{2j}$ for each $j$. And then take the fraction $\frac{ number(s_{1}-s_{2j}>0)}{10.000}$. If that fraction is lower than 0.05 then we can reject the null.

My intuition tells me that the above thinking is correct but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: Would it matter, in your logic, if your sample was drawn from a population with 0 skew, but wasn't gaussian in distribution?

Comment: Sure, but this is still a parametric test because your null hypothesis assumes that the true distribution is Gaussian. Essentially, you are comparing the data to Gaussian distribution, not to any distribution with 0 skewness... Further to the point: even if the test is formally valid, it may not be most powerful in a given situation. Skewness is such a well-research metric that I am sure your problem has been solved multiple times somewhere.

Comment: @stans-ReinstateMonica Because hypothesis test are equivalent to CI. I found out that I can use following CI:    $s_{1}\pm s.e(s_{1})$ , which doesn't care about the distribution of the sample https://brownmath.com/stat/shape.htm.

Comment: It sounds like you want either a permutation test comparing the skew to zero,  or a bootstrapped confidence interval of the sample skew, but in either case, wouldn't you resample the sample, not resample a known distribution?

Comment: @SalMangiafico In the bootstrap case I will create a CI. But in the permutation case  how I'm suppose to implement the hypothesis test ??I'm suppose to mix my sample with another gaussian sample ?

Comment: I think if you look up "one-sample permutation test", it will make sense, and I suspect you'll find a method appropriate for a skewness statistic. You will be resampling your sample, not using a known distribution.

Comment: Please start by clearly stating your null and alternative hypothesis (keeping in mind that these hypotheses are generally statements about a *population*); you should also clarify what kind of skewness you're referring to and mention any accompanying assumptions (e.g. that the variables are iid continuous)